# iOS - Pinterest Sharing Description Text not working if I send "&" in description text

Tags: ios, objective-c, pinterest

I had implemented pinterest sharing code in my app as well. Its working fine. But problem arrives at one scenario see follow

**Correct working**:

```
[pinterest createPinWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]
    sourceURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",shareUrl]] 
    description:@"My Description"];
```

Then it will share Pinterest Description same **My Description** as per my expectation.

But when I send **Description Test** like :

```
[pinterest createPinWithImageURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]
    sourceURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",shareUrl]] 
    description:@"My Details & Description"];
```

Then it will share Pinterest Description like **My Details**.
My expected text here is **My Details & Description** this is trunks my string after **&** symbol.

What actually wrong happening with me please look at here.

Comment: I want to handle it without third party

Comment: To adding a "%" after the "&" so it is "My Details &% Description" instead.

Comment: will try then tell you that will work or not...thanks @Erion

Comment: **@Erion** your solution is not working....

Comment: Have you found a solution yet then?

Comment: I just used below answer of **@JRG-Developer**

Comment: Try `@"My Details && Description"` or `@"My Details \& Description"`

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, Pinterest's [Pin It SDK](https://developers.pinterest.com/ios/) isn't open source, so it's difficult to find out what's really going on.

I would guess, however, that this method is creating a GET request under-the-hood that's incorrectly URL encoding the `description` parameter (perhaps they're using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` or some other naive method).

I'd recommend contacting the Pinterest SDK developers/maintainers to look into this.

As a quick fix, you might try URL encoding the `&` yourself. For example, you might try replacing `&` with `%26`, e.g.

```
NSString *description = // ...whatever it should be set to...
description = [description stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"%26"];
```

However, this might actually lead to other problems as the Pinterest SDK is likely doing *some sort of* URL encoding and would likely encode the `%` symbol.

Another naive approach may simply be to replace `&` with the word `and`, such as

```
NSString *description = // ...whatever it should be set to...
description = [description stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"and"];
```

Again, it's hacky, but it's a workaround for a bug that's likely in the underlying SDK.